# jquery assigning events to same element based on different selectors

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, event-handling

I am having an issue with binding jquery events.

I have a dropdownlist and for interests sake, I am using the chosen plugin. This has been used consistently through my web pages.

The following sample:

```
<select name="Title" class="form-control chosen-select" id="Title" style="display: none;"><option value=""></option>
<option value="TMR">Mr</option>
<option value="TMRS">Mrs</option>
<option value="TDR">Dr</option>
<option value="TMS">Miss</option>
</select>
```

Note the class contains chosen-select and the id=Title

The next bit is the html that is visible that is generated by chosen (which I believe is unnecessary for the question but explains the display:none above and I'm including for completeness)

```
<div title="" class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" id="Title_chosen" style="width: 100%;"><a tabindex="-1" class="chosen-single"><span>Mrs</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div><ul class="chosen-results"><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">Mr</li><li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="2">Mrs</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">Dr</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4">Miss</li></ul></div></div>
```

Now I have the following 'apply to all' code

```
$('.chosen-select').off('change').on('change', function () {
            alert('In chosen');               
        });
```

I always want this event to fire when any drop down list is changed. This is working fine.

Now I have a specific drop down list that I want to have a specific function to occur on a page, but I also want to have the above to fire. I am binding this to the id

```
$('#Title').off('change').on('change', function () {
                alert('title');
            });
```

What is happening in the case is that only the event on #Title fires.

The one solution that occurs to me is to put the 'catch-all' code into a function and simply call the function in the event handler as well as the #Title handler.

Is there a better or accepted way to do this? Or can my approach in general be improved?

As an aside the project is developed using MVC pattern using c# and Razor syntax.

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated

Comment: for a better solution, if you can state why you are using `off()` in your code, we might be able to give a better answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going to the reason to use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) as you have done, the solution is to use [events with namespace](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) like

```
$('.chosen-select').off('change.common').on('change.common', function () {
    alert('In chosen');
});

$('#Title').off('change.title').on('change.title', function () {
    alert('title');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Arun, the use of off() is unrelated. I had seen in another scenario that having the js on a partial page resulted in the event being bound multiple times. I was trying several things at the time of my question. Again, thank you for your help and pointing me in the right direction.